# Shadow goes wrong during device orientation

Tags: ios, rotation, calayer

I'm adding a shadow to a view (including a shadowPath so that performance is better) as follows:

```
CALayer *layer=aView.layer;
layer.shadowColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
layer.shadowOpacity=0.8f;
layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(4.0f,4.0f);
layer.shadowRadius=6.0f;
layer.masksToBounds=NO;
layer.shouldRasterize=YES;
layer.shadowPath=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:aView.bounds].CGPath;
```

But when the device is rotated and the view frame changes the shadow goes wrong (offset by a long way etc)

I have tried reseting the shadow in the layoutSubviews method but DURING the rotate you can see the shadow move across the screen.

What is the correct approach for dealing with shadow paths during rotation?

(As a last resort I am removing the shadow and then putting it back after the rotate but it's clunky and my view then has to be told when device orientation has been completed by its controller:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Is there a better way so a VIEW can know the rotation has COMPLETED?)

Comment: That's my problem too! :(